# Split Numpy array into equal-length sub-arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very huge numpy array like this:

```
np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , ... , 12345])
```

I need to create subgroups of `n` elements (in the example `n = 3`) in another array like this:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8], [...],  [12340, 12341, 12342], [12343, 12344, 12345]])
```

I did accomplish that using normal python lists, just appending the subgroups to another list. But, I'm having a hard time trying to do that in numpy.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Heard of `np.reshape`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.reshape(-1, 3)`, where the `-1` means "whatever's left".

```
>>> array = np.arange(1, 12346)
>>> array
array([    1,     2,     3, ..., 12343, 12344, 12345])
>>> array.reshape(-1, 3)
array([[    1,     2,     3],
       [    4,     5,     6],
       [    7,     8,     9],
       ..., 
       [12337, 12338, 12339],
       [12340, 12341, 12342],
       [12343, 12344, 12345]])
```

Comment: +1, Nice trick using the `-1`, the documentation mentioned "One shape dimension can be -1.", and this is a clever implementation of that.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use [`np.reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

From the documentation (link in title):

> **`numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')`**
>
> Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.

Here is an example of how you can apply it to your situation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12345])
>>> a.reshape((int(len(a)/3), 3))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 12345]], dtype=object)
```

*Note that obviously, the length of the `array` (`len(a)`) has to be a multiple of `3` to be able to `reshape` it into a `2-dimensional` `numpy` `array`, because they must be rectangular.*